# addressof-operator in c#

Tags: c#

In a winapi function I have to pass the address of the callback function
that function has to use.

So I declared a unsafe class and everything, but `bool* addressofmyfunction = &GetHandle;`
just won't compile!

Please help me or give me an alternative to passing the address like this.

Comment: What call are you trying to use?

Comment: Why is it a bool* for a function pointer?

Comment: Im trying to call Winapi function "EnumThreadWindows(int hwnd, int lpn, int lparam)"

Comment: what else can i use for a function-pointer?

Answer (score 5):

In .NET [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e(VS.80).aspx) are used to store pointers to functions. For example if you have the following function:

```
public int GetHandle(int arg1)
{ 
    return arg1 + 10;
}
```

it's address will be defined like so:

```
Func<int, int> addressOfMyFunction = GetHandle;
```

and you can invoke it like that:

```
int result = addressOfMyFunction(50);
```

Answer (score 2):

Function pointers are represented by delegates in C#. Since methods aren't moved by the garbage collector, you don't need to pin them (or use unsafe code) to pass them to a Win32 API function.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public delegate bool CallBack(int hwnd, int lParam);

public class EnumReportApp {

    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern int EnumWindows(CallBack x, int y); 

    public static void Main() 
    {
        CallBack myCallBack = new CallBack(EnumReportApp.Report);
        EnumWindows(myCallBack, 0);
    }

   public static bool Report(int hwnd, int lParam) { 
        Console.Write("Window handle is ");
        Console.WriteLine(hwnd);
        return true;
    }
}
```

There is a similar example for [EnumThreadWindows on pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/enumthreadwindows.html).

Comment: yes but getlastwin32error(); still tells me that i've used the wrong syntax!!

Comment: What's the exact error message? Can you show us your code that results in the error?

Comment: wow I'm really impressed by these fast and competent answeres!!
thank you very much this exaple on pinvoke.net really helped my I've ported the code wrong!! This Winapi is not very easy to port to c# isn't it?
I hope this will work now...

Comment: it seems to work now, but other functions do not work ,too.
ill have to continue tomorrow
by everybody

Answer (score 1):

`bool* addressofmyfunction = &GetHandle` won't compile in C or C++ either (the correct syntax would be `bool (*addressofmyfunction)() = &GetHandle`), but you can't do like that. I'm not an expert in interop, but I think you have to use `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`.